# How does stepwise ARIMA work?

Tags: time-series, arima, stepwise-regression

How does a stepwise ARIMA model work? I understand how ARIMA works but i didn't find any good material to understand about stepwise ARIMA. Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html

Comment: Thanks. So does it search a model for lower AIC using only four models 
ARIMA(0,d,0),ARIMA(2,d,2),ARIMA(1,d,0),ARIMA(0,d,1)?

Comment: Why have you included the `r` tag?

Comment: removed the R tag..wanted to know how its implemented in R.Rob's answer covers it

Comment: Then you did not have to remove the tag. Editing the post to include the information of your last comment could have been a more helpful thing to do (not too late for that).

Comment: http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA FLOW CHART.pdf details the enhanced iterative approach to detect the minimally sufficient arima model while validating the assumptions suggesting possible deterministic structure , changes in error variance over time and/or changes in model parameters over time rather than simply trying a fixed set of limited models. The data should be listened to in forming a useful model.

Comment: If you're talking about the pmdarima package in python.
The stepwise parameter is about how to go for CV. You can see the reference here : https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/tips_and_tricks.html#parallel-vs-stepwise